# Convolutional Layer Filters display in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I would like to extract the filters of conv2D layer and save them to files.

I used `Model.layers[i].weights` or `Model.layers[i].get_weights()`, and I am getting a 3D kernels with
`shape= (5,5,5,10)`, so I do not know if what I am printing is the layer output or the filters themselves, since I specified `kernel_size=(5,5)`, i.e. 5 5 1 and I am getting 5 5 5
input size to CONV2D 13 13 5 (channels_last).
output size of CONV2D 5 5 50 (filters=10).

```
layers.DepthwiseConv2D(kernel_size=(5,5), strides=(2,2),depth_multiplier=10, use_bias=False, dilation_rate=(1, 1)),
```

Comment: Yes, those are the filters, what is your question?

Comment: why am i getting 3 dimentional filters 5*5*5 while in the architecture i had from a research paper  states that kernels are 5*5*1? i thought that maybe i was printing the layer output and not the filters.

Comment: Filters always have a channels/depth component which depends on the number of inputs channels, so 2D filters actually have shape (channels, width, height).

Comment: fo following the architecture there is no way we can end with 10 filters being each 5*5*1 ie 25 parameters right? every filter here has 125 parameters?

Comment: What architecture are you talking about? The number of channels in the filters depends on the input to that layer.

Comment: Scaled Mean Pool Layer: This layer has 1 × 3 × 3 windows, and again outputs a multi-array of dimension 5 × 13 × 13.
Convolution Layer: This convolution has a kernel size of 1 × 5 × 5, a stride of (1, 2, 2), and a mapcount of 10. The output layer is therefore 50 × 5 × 5.